# I can't establish a connection between MongoDB and my website on NodeJS via Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to connect my local database, which is MongoDB with my website using Mongoose, but I am receiving Error 404. What I have to do in this situation?

--the next file is controller for my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = 'mongodb://localhost/employeers';
var Emp = require('../models/employeers');
mongoose.connect(db);
 module.exports.allEmployeers=function(req,res){
  console.log('getting information about everyone employeer');
  Emp.find({})
   .exec(function(err,employeers){
       if(err){
           res.send("Error has occured");
       }
       else{
           console.log(employeers);
           res.json(employeers);
       }
   })
};
```

--my route file

```
var ctrlEmployeers = require('../controllers/employeers');
router.get('/employeers', ctrlEmployeers.allEmployeers);
```

I expect when I enter localhost:3000/employeers in the browser, every employeer of my local database to be exported in JSON format. Instead of that I receive a 404 error: Page is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/employeers', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var Emp = require('../models/employeers');
    module.exports.allEmployeers=function(req,res){
  console.log('getting information about everyone employeer');
  Emp.find({})
   .exec(function(err,employeers){
       if(err){
           res.send("Error has occured");
       }
       else{
           console.log(employeers);
           res.json(employeers);
       }
   })
};
```